# UNIX Domain Socket programming 3 sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I am trying to make a server.c file that supports 3 sockets, which are represented by 3 respective client classes: client1, client2, client3.

In my server.c file, I currently have this code which I found on the internet.

If I wanted to make it have 3 sockets. I want to use the select() command to see the write activities of the 3 clients. My question is how can I use this to support 3 sockets.

Can I bind the 3 clients to 3 sockets that the server can listen to? If so, how can the server listen to these 3 sockets respectively? With an array possibly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define socket1 "sock1"
#define socket2 "sock2"
#define socket3 "sock3"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //struct sockaddr_un addr;
    struct sockaddr_un addr1;
    struct sockaddr_un addr2;
    struct sockaddr_un addr3;
    char buf[100];
    int socket1;
    int socket2;
    int socket3;
    //int fd;
    int cl,rc;

    if (argc > 1) socket_path=argv[1];

    if ( (socket1 = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&addr1, 0, sizeof(addr1));
    addr1.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr1.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr1.sun_path)-1);

    unlink(socket_path1);

    if ( (socket2 = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&addr2, 0, sizeof(addr2));
    addr1.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr2.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr2.sun_path)-1);

    unlink(socket_path2);

    if ( (socket3 = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    memset(&addr3, 0, sizeof(addr3));
    addr3.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr3.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr3.sun_path)-1);

    unlink(socket_path3);

    if (bind(socket1, (struct sockaddr*)&addr1, sizeof(addr1)) == -1) {
        perror("bind error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (bind(socket2, (struct sockaddr*)&addr2, sizeof(addr2)) == -1) {
        perror("bind error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (bind(socket3, (struct sockaddr*)&addr3, sizeof(addr3)) == -1) {
        perror("bind error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (listen(socket1, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (listen(socket2, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (listen(socket3, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {
        if ( (cl = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
            perror("accept error");
            continue;
        }

        while ( (rc=read(cl,buf,sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
            printf("read %u bytes: %.*s\n", rc, rc, buf);
        }
        if (rc == -1) {
            perror("read");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (rc == 0) {
            printf("EOF\n");
            close(cl);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you properly. I feel you're answering your own question. Yes, select is the way to listen on several sockets at the same time, with one thread. Basically you create an fd_set and use FD_SET to add sockets to that set...

Comment: I'll look into that. So FD is a data structure?, and I would add socket through a loop I assume?

Comment: Yeah fd_set is a structure, defined in sys/select.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want three listening sockets in the same process, you have to make them unique. In the [`AF_INET`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) family you do that by [`bind(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html)-ing different ports, in the [`AF_UNIX`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) family you do that with different paths.

Also your line:

```
char *socket_path = "\0hidden";
```

has at least two problems:

- Type of the string literal on the right side of the assignment is `const char[8]`, which decays to `const char*` pointer type, but not `char*` type. Make the left hand side `const char*`. Plus, **compile with higher warning level**, like `-Wall -pedantic` to get help from your compiler.
- Zero byte at the beginning of the string makes [`strncpy(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stpncpy.3.html) *not copy anything*, since it **`copies at most n characters from the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0')`**.

Create a function that take UNIX path as an argument and creates, binds, and marks socket as listening, and returns created socket descriptor. Call it three times - you have three listening UNIX sockets. Setup [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) on them for *reading* - that'll tell you when client connections arrive. At that point call [`accept(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) on the active socket to get *connected client socket*, which is separate from the listening socket itself.

Comment: But if I use INET, then those wouldn't be locally created sockets which UNIX provided right? or am I wrong?

Comment: You are working on a computer. Sockets are created on that computer. Clients on the same machine will be able to connect to both UNIX and INET sockets. Clients on other machines on the network will be able to connect to INET sockets, but not to UNIX sockets. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so. To verify.. would it be okay for me to update my code above to see if I have declared 3 separate sockets, and listening to them correctly?

Comment: @Michael, sorry, your question doesn't make much sense to me. Pick up a book on socket programming, or read online, e.g. here: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ - it's not perfect, but will get you going.

Comment: It's okay.. my background in C is poor. There was a restructuring of classes and all Java classes switched to C. I'll see what I can do. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Try compiling your code :) Your `fd` variable is not declared anywhere now.

Comment: Oh darn. fd ahah. Thanks. I'll keep going at it.

Comment: Seriously - create functions for common tasks. Copy-pasting same chunks of code is a well-known source of typos, errors, and is just really bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since select, is and has always been my *favorite* Unix syscall, I decided to do a little something, which is, in my humble opinion, what you were looking for.

I shamelessly took server's and client's code from here:
https://troydhanson.github.io/misc/Unix_domain_sockets.html

I did of course some little modifications, to make it fit your needs, lets see:

server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *socket_path = "/tmp/socket";

int main() {
  int fd, i;
  int clients[10], num_clients;
  fd_set read_set;
  char buf[100];

  struct sockaddr_un addr;

  if ( (fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  unlink(socket_path);

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (listen(fd, 5) == -1) {
    perror("listen error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  num_clients = 0;

  while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_SET(fd, &read_set);

    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {
      FD_SET(clients[i], &read_set);
    }

    select(fd + num_clients + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_set)) {
      if ( (clients[num_clients++] = accept(fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
        perror("accept error");
        continue;
      }
      printf("we got a connection!\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_clients; i++) {
      if (FD_ISSET(clients[i], &read_set)) {
        read(clients[i], buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("client %d says: %s\n", i, buf);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

client.c:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *socket_path = "/tmp/socket";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  char buf[100];
  int fd,rc;

  if ( (fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);

  if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("connect error");
    exit(-1);
  }

  while( (rc=read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
    printf("writing\n");
    *index(buf, '\n') = 0;

    if (write(fd, buf, rc) != rc) {
      if (rc > 0) fprintf(stderr,"partial write");
      else {
        perror("write error");
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Ok, this works very easily, you just fire the server in one terminal, and then you open a couple other terminals and fire a couple clients.

Running it on my pc I get:

```
exe@atreides:~/tmp$ ./server 
we got a connection!
client 0 says: Hello!
we got a connection!
client 1 says: Hey man!
```

Another terminal at the same time:

```
exe@atreides:~/tmp$ ./client 
Hey man!
writing
```

And in another:

```
exe@atreides:~/tmp$ ./client 
Hello!
writing
```

The magic behind all this is to properly use socket and select.

First you need a server socket, the one that will accept connections.

Once you bind to a server socket, let it be a Unix socket or a network socket, you can get sockets to your clients by accepting connections on that socket. Each client gets a new socket number.

Then, you add these sockets, the server socket and the clients socket to an fd_set and pass it to select. Select will listen on all sockets at the same time and will leave in the set those who have received data.

Now you iterate the set to see what sockets are hot and, you're there!

One more thing, which I guess was confusing you, all clients connect to the *same* server socket address (file). Yes it is like if many processes opened the same file, at the same time... But this isn't an ordinary file, it is a Unix socket. :)

Have fun and good luck!!!

Comment: I think you might have a bug in your maxfd calculation in the server, it's not just the count, it is the max of any fd added, +1: "This is an integer one more than the maximum of any file descriptor in any of the sets. In other words, while adding file descriptors to each of the sets, you must calculate the maximum integer value of all of them, then increment this value by one, and then pass this as nfds."